# same size dataframe compare

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframe of same size ( same rows)  and I would like to do a cell by cell comparison. what is the best way to achieve this? if df_diff length is > 0, we have differences.
Currently, I am doing it as below :

df_diff = pd.concat([dfstage,dfprod]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

---

Also, since my dataframe has 50 columns, I want to loop through each column and find the cell which doesnt match.

so df_diff :

col1  col2  col3  col4 col5  col6  col7
abc   12    True  10   15    20    21
abc   12    false  10  15    20    22

I want to output col3 and col7 based on the key col1.

---

Any other suggestions?
Using this code:
df_diff = pd.concat([df_stage,df_prod]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

I see the difference between two frames but now I want to narrow this down and only show columns which have different values.

---

So improved my comparison`enter code here` to look like this:

```
for rows_stage, rows_prod in zip(df_stage.iterrows(), df_prod.iterrows()):
                boolmatch = rows_stage == rows_prod
                print(boolmatch.all())
```

But i get an error
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

use pandas [dataframe.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)

it returns a true if they are equal.

```
df_diff=dfstage.equal(dfprod)
```